# how to get div tag contains an img tag by using regular expression javascript

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a generated string like this

```html
tesgddedd<br> <div><img style="max-width: 10rem;" src="folder/mypicture.jpg"><div> <br></div></div>
```

I want to get div contains img and to add css class in this div to have a new string like this

```html
tesgddedd<br> <div class="myCssClass"><img style="max-width: 10rem;" src="folder/mypicture.jpg"><div> <br></div></div>
```

I tried this method

```js
let myString = 'tesgddedd<br> <div><img style="max-width: 10rem;" src="folder/mypicture.jpg"><div> <br></div></div>'
console.log('My new String with div class  : ',myString.match(/<div [^>]*img="[^"]*"[^>]*>/gm)[0])
```

It doesn't work.

How can I do it please?

Comment: Use a html parser please. Otherwise here are some pointers: https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/

Answer (score 2):

Recommend using an HTML parser instead of regex and using `.querySelector` to grab the `div` with `img`.

Using native browser interface [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and [.parseFromString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString) to parse HTML.

```js
const generatedHTML = "tesgddedd<br> <div><img style='max-width: 35rem;' src='folder/mypicture.jpg'><div> <br></div></div>";

const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(generatedHTML, "text/html");

// Retrieve element that is a div that contains a direct img as child
// Note: it also returns other children as well
const divWithImg = doc.querySelector("div:has(> img)");

if (divWithImg) {
  // Captured div with img
  console.log("Before", divWithImg);
  
  // Add class
  divWithImg.className = "myCssClass"
  
  // Updated div with class name
  console.log("After", divWithImg);
} else {
  console.log("No match found.");
}
```

*Below snippet for visual example*

```js
const generatedHTML = "tesgddedd<br> <div><img style='max-width: 35rem;' src='folder/mypicture.jpg'><div> <br></div></div>";

const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(generatedHTML, "text/html");

// Retrieve element that is a div that contains a direct img as child
// Note: it also returns other children as well
const divWithImg = doc.querySelector("div:has(> img)");

if (divWithImg) {
  // Used to just preview on page
  const code = document.querySelector("code");
  
  // Captured div with img
  code.textContent = `
    Before:
    ${divWithImg.outerHTML}
   `;
  console.log("Before", divWithImg);
  
  // Add class
  divWithImg.className = "myCssClass"
  
  // Updated div with class name
  code.textContent += `
    After:
    ${divWithImg.outerHTML}
   `;
  console.log("After", divWithImg);
} else {
  console.log("No match found.");
}
```

```html
<pre><code></code></pre>
```